# Loop through bootstrap accordion rails issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an issue to loop through profile field and values. Bootstrap collapse not working.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <% @profile.each do |field, value| %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="collapse_#{field.id}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <%= field%>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse_#{field.id}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
         <div class="panel-body">
           <%= value %>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

Comment: First correct rails code "#{field.id}"  it should be <%= field.id %> I think you have to change from href="collapse_#{field.id}"  to href="#collapse_<%= field.id %> " or change href to data-target="#collapse_<%= field.id %> "

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <% @profile.each do |field, value| %>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="collapse_<%=field.id%>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <%= field%>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse_<%=field.id%>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
         <div class="panel-body">
           <%= value %>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

You can use <%= field.id%> insted of #{field.id}.